# Rails bootstrap form_for posting new data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the `User` model and I have the `authenticate` controller and in routes I marked it as resources.

```
resources :authenticate
```

Now I have this in my index method for `authenticate`

```
def index
    @user = User.new
end
```

And I use it like this:

```
<%= form_form @user, url: authenticate_path(@user) do |u| %>
```

But whenever I submit, it says that route not found, missing user id. But there's no user id, it's a new record?...

Is that a wrong way of adding new records?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`authenticate_path` returns the path for the `#show` method in the authenticate resources.  It is expecting an ID in this context.  To reference the `create` path, you should use `authenticates_path`. So,

`<%= form_for @user, url: authenticate_index_path do |u| %>`

Comment: Undefined variable or method authenticates_path

Comment: Hi Jony - that is because you are using the singular form for resources `resources :authenticate`, which changes the routes a bit.  I've updated the answer to reflect this change.  You'll need to use `authenticate_index_path` instead.  Or, I'd recommend changing your resources to `resources :authenticates` and use `authenticates_path` from the original answer.